# Multiple django sites on elastic beanstalk

Tags: django, apache, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an existing EB environment for `example1.com`, I have a few small side projects (`example2.com`, `example3.com`) that I would like to run on the same environment.

I already know that I can have a custom apache `httpd.conf` file and have it overwrite the default as part of the deployment. So I'm thinking it should be possible to add virtual hosts to my custom `httpd.conf`.

And with the following project sructure it should work:

```
base_folder/
    my_httpd.conf
    requirements.txt
    .ebextensions/
    .elasticbeanstalk/
    example1/
        <django project for example1>
    example2/
        <django project for example2>
    example3/
        <django project for example3>
```

My questions:

- Will it work? what are the necessary steps to have it up and running?
- Assuming it's possible, is it also possible to have a different virtualenv for each project or is that asking for too much?

Comment: Hello, It has been years but did you found out how to achieve that?. Did that work?